# passing argument from one view to another view

Tags: views

I have created two views , View1 has a list of city names (drop down select box) and View2 displays all the pharma shops across multiple cities. What i am trying to do is , when a city is choosen from view1 i need to display only the pharma shops in that city using view2. I am using drupal 7 and have no knowledge on php. Is there a way to achieve this without doing any coding? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two separate views for that.

Step 1: Install [Address Field Module](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield)

Step 2: "Create a content type let say "Pharma Shops" , add adress field to this content type.

Step 3: Add some nodes to this content type, so you can see the results filtering with your views.

Step 4: Create view of type content for "Pharma Shops", add fields you want to show for the nodes in the display and search to find views setting for exposed filters,where again you will be exposing address field to all users to filter down the results.

As a Note: Consider view as ui to make database queries.